# Pass along contents of XML node for additional processing in XSLT

Tags: xml

I have a long, human-generated XML file with enough regularity for me to identify its contents using Xpath. I'm trying to reformat it as an HTML table.

The source material is technically formatted as a table just for visual effect (don't get me started). Where I am running into trouble is the descriptive part of each entry can contain arbitrary markup, which I need to pass along for additional processing. I haven't figured out how to get the contents of the description and process them appropriately.

I'm not getting the desired results using value-of or copy-of. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Sample doc:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manual>
    <body>
        <chapter>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry>
                            <para>Some parameter name</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <para>1</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry>
                            <para>Range</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <para>1–10</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>
                            <para>Description</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <para>Sets the type of process module.</para>
                            <para>There can be <emphasis>more arbitrary markup</emphasis> in here.</para>
                            <list>
                                <item>Even a list</item>
                            </list>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </chapter>
    </body>
</manual>
```

I've been trying variations on the following XSLT snippet

```xml
        <xsl:for-each select="table"> 
        <tr>
            <!-- insert additional code here -->
            <td class="desc"> <xsl:value-of select="//tbody/row[2]/entry[2]/*"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:value-of> </td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over-thinking it. Or perhaps under-thinking it.

```xml
<td class="desc">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tgroup/tbody/row[2]/entry[2]/*" />
</td>
```